# why prototype need a instance not the function self

Tags: javascript

When we use prototype . we use like

```
function classA(){

}
function classB(){

}

classB.prototype = new classA();
```

why should we write it like that? why isn't it?

```
classB.prototype = classA;
```

after I set the prototype is classA; then I log the classB.prototype. the console log like following

function classA(){
}

what's that mean? I try to add some method into classA but I can NOT call them by using classB.prototype.BLABLA.

my english is not so good. so . I don't know if I explain it well or not.

Comment: This is because JavaScript is **not** object oriented (in which case you inherit from class, i.e. function in JS), but it is **prototype** oriented (you inherit from objects). And a consequence of a word *prototype* is: "make new object with prototype as a basis".

Comment: @freakish: JavaScript *is* object-oriented, it just does not have class-based inheritance.

Comment: @FelixKling: well, actually it's just a matter of words. For me object oriented programming always includes class inheritance. This point of view is popularized by wiki as well.

Comment: @freakish: Yeah, terminology is always something to argue about ;) But Wikipedia also has [this article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype-based_programming): *"Prototype-based programming is a style of object-oriented programming..."*. Anyways, I got your point.

Comment: @freakish thanks for the answer. but I made some experiment to figure out what happened when using classB.prototype = classA; I edit the question again.  could  you help me .? thx a lot. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> why isn't it? `classB.prototype = classA;`

Because all instances of `classB` would inherit from **the function** `classA` which is usually not what you want. Instances of `classB` would inherit all properties of function objects, such as [`.call` *<sup>[MDN]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) and [`.apply` *<sup>[MDN]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply). They would not inherit properties you assigning to an instance inside the constructor function or to the prototype of `classA`.

> why should we write it like that?

You want each instance of `classB` having the same properties as an **instance** of `classA`.

---

But even `classB.prototype = new classA();` is not a very good approach. What if `classA` expects arguments passed to the constructor?

Better let instances of `classB` inherit from `classA`'s prototype, like:

```
classB.prototype = Object.create(classA.prototype);
classB.prototype.constructor = classB;
```

And in the constructor, you are calling the parent constructor on the new instance:

```
function classB(){
    classA.apply(this, arguments);
}
```

**Reference**: [`Object.create`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create)

Comment: @gdoron: Yeah, I should make less comments and provide more answers :D Just sometimes I think, people who are willing to put more time into it might provide better ones...

Comment: Note that if the browser doesn't support `Object.create` by default, you can create your own (a la Javascript the Good Parts by Douglas Crockford) by using `if (typeof Object.create !== 'function') {Object.create = function (o) {var F = function () {};F.prototype = o; return new F();};`

Answer (score 1):

Simply because the prototype is an object, not a function.

`classA` is a function, so you don't use it as prototype. You create an instance of `classA` so that you get an object.

As a function actually also is an object, you *could* use a function as prototype, but that would only be confusing.

Answer (score 0):

> why prototype need a instance not the function self

That's what allows you to extend your child class from parent or get stuff of parent class in your child classes. It is the same concept as in other languages where to get stuff from parent class, child class has to create an instance of it in its constructor function.

Without creating an instance, you won't be able to get the memebrs of parent class in your child class.

Observe:

```
function classA(){
  this.foo = function(){ alert('i am in parent'); }
}
function classB(){

}

classB.prototype = new classA();

var b = new classB;
b.foo(); // alerts "foo"
```

And:

```
function classA(){
  this.foo = function(){ alert('i am in parent'); }
}
function classB(){

}

classB.prototype = classA();

var b = classB;
b.foo(); // error: Object # has no method 'foo'
```

Comment: In his question his asking for `classB.prototype = classA` unlike your answer: `classB.prototype = classA();` Sorry for bothering you...